# angular google maps warning " The second argument to new LatLng() was ignored and can be removed. "

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps api in my project. When i call google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation() function i'll got a lot of warning in console and as a result freezing system.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

in my code:

```
  isPolygonIntersect(poly1: google.maps.LatLng[] | google.maps.LatLngLiteral[], poly2: google.maps.LatLng[] | google.maps.LatLngLiteral[]): boolean {
    let isIntersect: boolean = false;
    let mainPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({paths:poly1});

    poly2.forEach((literal:  google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral) => {
      console.log('isPolygonIntersect', literal, mainPolygon);
      if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(literal, mainPolygon)) {

        isIntersect = true;

        
      }

      
    });
    let secondPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({paths:poly2});
    poly1.forEach((literal:  google.maps.LatLng | google.maps.LatLngLiteral) => {
      if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(literal, secondPolygon)) {
        isIntersect = true;
      }
    });
    return isIntersect;
  }
```

Dependencies:

```
"@angular/cli": "~16.1.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^16.1.4",
"@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
"@angular/google-maps": "^16.1.4",
"@types/google.maps": "^3.53.4",
"jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~5.1.3"
```

P.S. Its happen after Angular update, and librarys update.
I experemented with version but it didn't work.

Im tryed to upgrade/downgrade version of @angular/google-maps, but no results yet.

Comment: This has already been reported in Public Issue Tracker and the fix will be included in the next version release.You can view the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/290820819).

Answer (score 0):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=

You need to add version(v=3) to it. it will definitely resolve your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Setting v=3 didn't work, however setting v=3.52 (the old version) did work for my project.